# Why the leafs of a gold-leaf electroscope close together?

Tags: electricity

I understand why the leafs of the apparatus repel, but why do they close together after we ground the apparatus?

Are the two gold leafs are attracting each other? Or are they closing because of gravity, (i.e. under their own weight)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're likely seeing are the leafs returning to their natural, uncharged state. They are not attracting each other. Their close proximity is due in part to gravity, as you say, but also the particular shape of the supporting apparatus.